# inner join with containable cakephp

Tags: cakephp, join, cakephp-2.3

I have 3 tables, `restaurants`, `orders`, `users`. orders table has fields `restaurant_id`, `status` and `user_id`.

```
restaurant -> hasMany orders
orders belogsTo Restaurant
orders belongsTo users
```

I need to find only those restaurants that have order with status = 1, and at the same time need to fetch user's info.

So, I am making inner join with orders table,

```
$options['joins'] = array(
    array('table' => 'orders',
        'alias' => 'Order',
        'type' => 'INNER',
        'conditions' => array(
            'Restaurant.id = Order.restaurant_id',
        )
    )
);
```

But how Can I also get users' information along with this, because according to cake documentation http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#joining-tables, allowed params here are `table, alias, type, conditions`. Is there a some way that I can embed the sql query of getting user's info in the final query? Yes, the alternative will be to write the custom query, but is not there a way to do with cake.

Thanks

**update**

The best solution in this case was to write custom sql query.

Comment: Write the query you actually want in SQL, and include that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you just tried an additional Join to get the Users as well?

Something like this:

```
$this->Restaurant->find('all', array(
    'joins' => array(
        array('table' => 'orders',
            'alias' => 'Order',
            'type' => 'INNER',
            'conditions' => array(
                'Restaurant.id = Order.restaurant_id',
                'Order.status = 1'
            )
        ),
        array('table' => 'users',
            'alias' => 'User',
            'type' => 'RIGHT',
            'conditions' => array(
                'Order.user_id = User.id'
            )
    ),

));
```

Note:  What I usually find easiest (with complicated queries that you're having trouble figuring out) is to build the query 100% in SQL and get it working to your liking, then just re-build it in CakePHP.

Comment: But the restaurant is not associated with user, will this work, ok, lemme give it a try

Comment: @Davo Right, but because you're joining with the orders table in the first join, you should then be able to create a join(s) off of it.

Comment: does not work, return empty. I do in the same way, so, here I should just left join orders with users, but if I write that query inside the condition in cake it throws an error

Answer (score 0):

List of orders with status 1 and with restaurant and user info:

```
$this->Restaurant->Order->find('all', array('conditions'=>array('Order.status'=>1), 'contain'=>array('Restaurant', 'User')))
```

Comment: And how to do this with paginate ?